# Conflicting wiring diagrams

Tags: wiring, lighting

I've spent the morning looking at YouTube videos and I feel I've gotten my wiring correct.

I'm trying to add a rose / pendant to a room. As I took the original light off, I noticed there is only 1 set of cables (set of 3 cables). As such, I don't believe there is any looping required.

The problem I have, is the light isn't working and my first assumption is that it's due to my wiring.

However, I've now seen a video which potentially conflicts with the wiring diagram.

This is a screenshot of a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoVSdqeFkhE

Please ignore the green arrow

[image]

And this is the instruction sheet which came with the pendant

[image]

These 2 seem to conflict. Am I reading this wrong? Or does it not matter in which hole within the terminal block it goes?

And another diagram shows something totally differnt:

[image]

If it helps, this is my effort

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a rose / pendant to a room. As I took the original light off, I noticed there is only 1 set of cables (set of 3 cables). As such, I don't believe there is any looping required.

I think what you mean is you have one cable with three wires - black red and bare.

> However, I've now seen a video which potentially conflicts with the wiring diagram.

I didn't watch the video but the screen shot can't work, it doesn't even have one of the current carrying conductors terminated.  I'd ignore it.

First thing you need to do is reconcile the lampholder's color coding.  It appears to follow the new UK wiring color scheme:

- Line:  brown
- Neutral:  blue
- Protective Earth:  none present

It looks like your house wiring follows the old UK color scheme:

- Line:  red
- Neutral:  black
- Protective Earth: green with yellow stripe

If this is the case, you'll land

- fixture brown wire and house red wire on LIVE (as it is)
- fixture blue wire and house black wire on Neutral (move black wire)
- House PE on earth lug (as it is)

Again this is ***assuming*** the color codes are as expected.  To be really safe you'd want to verify.

Comment: Hi. Because it's electricity, and although your post is very clear (thank you), can I still clarify that this means nothing in the loop? Essentially I'm swapping the red cable from the red to the live?

Comment: @Dave - I agree that you're right to ask for clarification in the interest of safety. 
 You read me right, nothing will be in the loop terminal, just move the red wire.  You were very close :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to match your situation up to the wrong diagram. The diagrams vary because the applications vary.

- Power is supplied at the lamp, and goes no further. There is a spur (switch loop) for the light switch. (6 wires + earth)
- Power is supplied at the lamp, and constant power is carried onward to other loads. There is a spur (switch loop) for the light switch, which switches this lamp only.  (8 wires + earth)
- Power is supplied at the lamp, and goes no further. There is a spur (switch loop) for the light switch, which also switches this and other lamps.  Switched power is carried onward to those other lamps.  (8 wires + earth)
- Power is supplied at the switch and powers only this lamp.  (4 wires + earth)
- Power is supplied at the switch, and powers this lamp and also onward lamp(s).  (6 wires + earth)

The splice blocks are designed to have enough screws for all the above cases.  There are yet other cases, but they are outliers.